# Yii::app()->user->id sometimes gives empty result

Tags: php, heroku, yii

Hosted on Heroku
Yii 1.14
PHP 5.6

A stranger error when Yii::app()->user->id returns the id sometimes but at other times returns empty. The same page load results in this strange behaviour.

I check for this in a parent class called AdminController.php

```
class AdminController extends CController
{
public $partnerCount;
public $vendorCount;
public $plantationMarkers;

public function init()
{
    echo Yii::app()->user->id;

    if(empty(Yii::app()->user->id)) {
        echo 'User id empty: '. Yii::app()->user->id;
        //$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('admin/auth/login'));
        exit;
        return false;
    }
    elseif(!Yii::app()->user->checkAccess(User::PARTNER)) {
        $this->layout = 'column1';
        $this->render('/auth/not-authorized');
        return false;
    }

    $this->partnerCount = $this->getPartnerCount();
    $this->vendorCount = $this->getVendorCount();

    $this->plantationMarkers = $this->getPlantationMarkers();

    return true;
}
```

So in this code 'User id empty: ' is echoed in some cases while in other cases I get the id.

The point is with no change in code how can this work at some time while not at other times.

Comment: be sure in not related to session timeout . and then your loging credentials are expired

Comment: Its not. If I reload the page a second time or any other time the id value is there. The problem is only on heroku installation while my local installation works fine.

Comment: Just a side comment. you should not evaluate id to check if user is logged in or not, use: Yii::app()->user->isGuest

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the session to be stored in DB table. I am not sure but there was some issue with Yii storing session on the server under Heroku.
The change is required in the config array under 'components'.

From :

```
        'session' => array(
            'class' => 'CHttpSession',
            'timeout' => 2400,
            'cookieParams' => array(
                    'httpOnly' => true,
                    'secure' => false,
            ),
    ),
```

To :

```
        'session' => array(
            'timeout' => 2400,
            'cookieParams' => array(
                    'httpOnly' => true,
                    'secure' => false,
            ),
            'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
            'connectionID' => 'db',
            'sessionTableName' => 'lig_session',
    ),
```

Comment: It would be interesting if you share the portion of the code where you start user session